# How to add content to an Spring oauth2 access token?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

If I understand the oauth2 spec correctly I should be able to add custom content like an user_id to the oauth2 access token. The server can then decode the access-token and add an User Domain Object to the SecurityContextHolder.

(Of course I could add the user_id to every REST API method but this would mean a lot of refactoring)

Right now from reading the manual I think that I need to implement or extend a TokenEnhancer. Since I am using a javascript client maybe
I should extend JwtAccessTokenConverter? Am I on the right path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first why you need to ad userId to the Access token while you can store your data in Scope or additional_information, let me describe using scope:

if your client need to get the specific data with the access token you can send as scope param to Auth server and then when redirect access toke to redirection URL you will get data you put in scope param, this is used to store stat of your user before and after authentication.

if you want this user Id for something else rather than storing state I suggest to make endpoint on the Auth server to provide user details and secure it with OAuth with Access token.

I do not suggest to put any data is generation of the Access token as it could weak the complexity of the token, also it is not recommended to decode your token at client side.

Comment: thank you for the answer. my idea is that the server (endpoint) decodes the access-token and with the help of the user_id adds the User to the SecurityContextHolder

Comment: check the sql of Access Token table it is contains already user_name so you can got it from DB direct, no need to decode it. and if your endpoint have no access to this DB, you can do endpoint on auth server exposing the user profile based on access token, and this request to be secured by the OAuth too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new TokenEnhancer() {
        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken, OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication) {
            DefaultOAuth2AccessToken newToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(oAuth2AccessToken);
            Map<String, Object> addInfo = new HashMap<>();
            // add here what u need
            addInfo.put("putName", oAuth2Authentication.getName());
            newToken.setAdditionalInformation(addInfo);
            return newToken;
        }
    };
}
```

and at AuthorizationServerConfiguration:

```
@Autowired
private TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer;
...
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
            .tokenEnhancer(this.tokenEnhancer);
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you add a small explanation of your answer in order for us to understand what you are doing.